# How to delete entry from database, script delete wrong entry

Tags: php, sql, database, sql-delete

I need script to delete registered users from database. It is working but not how it should.
My script delete last entry instead of entry I clicked on?
Here is my script for listing entries.

```
    <form action="user_delete.php" method="post">
<?php 
error_reporting(0);
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE status='member' ORDER BY id_user";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

    $id_c=$record['id_user'];
    $mail=$record['mail'];
    $_SESSION["del_user"]=$id_c;


$user = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id_user='$id_c'"), 0);

echo "Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>$user</b><br />";
echo "E-mail korisnika:&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>$mail</b><br />";
echo "ID:&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>$id_c</b><br /><br />";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"delete_row\" class=\"btn\" value=\"Delete\" />";
echo "<hr />";
}
?>
</form>
```

And this is my user_delete.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'function.php';
include 'db_config.php';
$del=$_SESSION["del_user"];

    $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id_user = $del";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_affected_rows()>0)
    {
        header("Location:user_management.php");
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "No";
    }  

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Read through your code. You have 10 users, and output 10 delete buttons, but you're storing the id of the **LAST** user in $_SESSION... you'll never be able to delete anything EXCEPT the last user that was output. You need to store the ids of the users in the form, and pass that id back to the script.

Comment: Ok, I realise problem, but how to solve it? To do this without while loop?

Comment: basically: `<input type="submit" value="$id_of_user" name="submit"`, then `$id = $_POST['submit']`.

Comment: IT WORKS thank you. so simple change :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

In your while loop, you are overwriting the session variable `del_user`:

```
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

    $id_c=$record['id_user'];
    $mail=$record['mail'];
    $_SESSION["del_user"]=$id_c;
```

This means that `$_SESSION["del_user"]` will always be the last record.

Comment: Ok I understand that, but how to fix that? How to select and show users from db to not overwrite id? Or how to send rigth id to script?

Answer (score -1):

Pass your POST variable for email OR primary key of that table. Right now you are pchecking with session id. It will delete only your record every time.

```
$del = $_POST['email'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id_user = $del";
```

Comment: So, What you want him to do. Put variables in session? That's not the elegant way. it's also a hack.

Comment: Recommending that he used prepared statements to execute these queries.